# Ruby roo Excel.new

Tags: ruby, excel, ruby-roo

I have a question regarding the ruby roo library. There is a method for opening the Excel document Excel.new . How to close this document, having worked with it?

Answer (score 1):

To work-around, I opened two classes to add methods that would help me get to the IO object.

```
Excel.class_eval do
  def get_workbook
    @workbook
  end
end

Spreadsheet::Excel::Workbook.class_eval do
  def get_io
    @io
  end
end
```

Then, my processing code now looks like this:

```
    xls = Excel.new(@@filename)

    ...#do processing here

    xls.get_workbook.get_io.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation there's no method to call, it might just close it when the script ends

But maybe you can try something like (not tested)

```
Excel.new do |excel|
  # Your stuff here
end
```